# CABasicAnimation unlimited repeat without HUGE_VALF?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, animation, repeat, cabasicanimation

I'm trying to perform auto repeat of my image rotation animation with CABasicAnimation. I have tried to search on web how to set such property but was unable to find that. Is it really no such property for CA animation? I know that you can set some huge value ([here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/AnimatingLayers.html)) to repeatCount property but hey, why then does UIView animateWithDuration has an option UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat and what the value is hardcoded for it?

Comment: The value is `1e50`, in `math.h`.

Comment: In XCode ⌘-click to go to the definition of something.

Answer (score 143, accepted):

No, this is the way you're supposed to do it according to [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAMediaTiming_protocol/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/CAMediaTiming).

> Setting this property to `HUGE_VALF` will cause the animation to repeat forever.

---

**Update for Swift:**

HUGE_VALF is not exposed to Swift. However, my understanding from [this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/HUGE_VAL) is that HUGE_VALF is intended to be infinity (in fact, `INFINITY` is defined as `HUGE_VALF`). Since Swift's `FloatingPointType` protocol provides a `static var infinity`, you can simply write

```
myAnimation.repeatCount = .infinity
```

Comment: in iOS 7 and above , it stops after certain interval.Not sure whats the reason though.

Comment: `Float.infinity` in Swift. Referred docs mention `HUGE_VALF` but doesn't tell how to express same in Swift.

Answer (score 8):

> For swift 3.0 and above

```
              let rotationAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.z")
          rotationAnimation.fromValue = 0
          rotationAnimation.toValue = CGFloat.pi * 2
          rotationAnimation.duration = 1
          rotationAnimation.repeatCount = .infinity
          holderView.btnRefresh.layer.add(rotationAnimation, forKey: "spinAnimation")
```